# SQL Server UPDATE with WHERE spanning over 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server database and I need to manually do an update query. There for no solutions using any programming language can be used.(stored procedures can be used)

I have 4 tables affected (/used) in the query.

- [Orders]
- [StatusHistoryForOrder]
- [StatusHistory]
- [Statuses]

I need to update the field [Orders].[OrderStatusID] which is a foreign key to [Statuses]. (So actually changing the state of the order. The table [StatusHistoryForOrder] is a linking table to [StatusHistory] and only contains 2 colums.

- [StatusHistoryForOrder].[OrderId]
- [StatusHistoryForOrder].[OrderStatusHistoryid]

Don't say that this is not logically cause I already know that. The company who designed the database is a complete retarded company but the database is now too large to set things straight and there is neither the time or money to do it.

The [StatusHistory] table has multiple columns:

- [StatusHistory].[OrderStatusHistoryId]
- [StatusHistory].[OrderStatusId]
- [StatusHistory].[Date]
- [StatusHistory].[Message]

The [StatusHistory].[OrderStatusId] is also a foreign key to [Statuses].

In the update query I need to update the status of the order to status 16. But only on rows that now have status 1 and are older then 60 days. I know I can check the date by using the function

```
DATEDIFF(DD,[StatusHistory].[Date],GETDATE()) > 60
```

But how to implement this query if the date field is not in the orders. And to set the new [StatusHistory] a new row has to be made for that table and the [StatusHistoryForOrder] table also needs a new row and the ID of that row needs to be set in the [Orders] table row.

Does anyone know how to do this? I am fairly new to SQL Server (or SQL for that matter) and I have absolutly no clue where to begin.

Conclusion:

I need a stored procedure that first checks every row in [Orders] if the [StatusHistory].[Date] (which is linked to the order using foreign keys) of that order is older that 60. If it is older then a new StatusHistory row must be inserted with the current date and status 16. Then in [StatusHistoryForOrder] a new row must be inserted with the new ID of the statusHistory been set in [StatusHistoryForOrder].[OrderStatusHistoryid] and the order id set in [StatusHistoryForOrder].[OrderId]. And last but not least: The [Orders].[OrderStatusID] also needs to be set to 16.

---

A select query to select the date and status of the order:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.Orders.OrderID, 
    dbo.Statuses.Description AS Status, 
    dbo.StatusHistory.Date
FROM         
    dbo.Orders 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Statuses 
ON 
    dbo.Orders.OrderStatusID = dbo.Statuses.StatusId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.StatusHistoryForOrder 
ON 
    dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.StatusHistoryForOrder.OrderId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.StatusHistory 
ON 
    dbo.StatusHistoryForOrder.OrderStatusHistoryid = dbo.StatusHistory.OrderStatusHistoryId
WHERE     
    (dbo.Statuses.StatusId = 1) 
AND 
    (DATEDIFF(DD, dbo.StatusHistory.Date, GETDATE()) > 60)
```

---

**UPDATE**
For @marc_s:

[image: Column info]

---

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: @marc_s Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. Installed using WPI. Also using: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Don't you have a business layer?

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger,, I have no clue what you are talking about. Like I said I am fairly new to this.

Comment: @SynerCoder: I mean a piece of software written in a high level programming language which implements the business logic and is responsible for consistency.

Comment: @SynerCoder: If you have your business logic in asp, you may write the logic there instead of a stored procedure. Unless you are forced to write a SP because of performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CTE (Common Table Expression) to find all those orders - does it work, are the results plausible? (this doesn't update anything just yet - just SELECTing for now):

```
USE (your database name here)
GO

DECLARE @OrdersToUpdate TABLE (OrderID INT, StatusHistoryID INT, StatusDate DATETIME)

;WITH RelevantOrders AS
(
    SELECT 
       o.OrderId, sh.Date
    FROM dbo.Orders o
    INNER JOIN dbo.StatusHistoryForOrder ho ON ho.OrderId = o.OrderId
    INNER JOIN dbo.StatusHistory sh ON ho.OrderStatusHistoryid = sh.OrderStatusHistoryid 
    WHERE
       sh.Date <= DATEADD(D, -60, GETDATE())   -- older than 60 days back from today
       AND o.OrderStatusID = 1                 -- status = 1
)
INSERT INTO @OrdersToUpdate(OrderID, StatusDate)
   SELECT OrderID, [Date] 
   FROM RelevantOrders

BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @OrderIDToInsert INT,         -- OrderID to process
            @InsertedStatusHistoryID INT  -- new ID of the inserted row in StatusHistory

    -- grab the first OrderID that needs to be processed
    SELECT TOP 1 @OrderIDToInsert = OrderID
    FROM @OrdersToUpdate
    WHERE StatusHistoryID IS NULL
    ORDER BY OrderID

    -- as long as there are still more OrderID to be processed ....
    WHILE @OrderIDToInsert IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
       PRINT 'Now inserting new StatusHistory entry for OrderID = ' + CAST(@OrderIDToInsert AS VARCHAR(10))

       INSERT INTO dbo.StatusHistory(OrderStatusID, [Date], [Message])
       VALUES(16, GETDATE(), 'Bulk Insert/Update operation')   -- enter here whatever you want to store 

       SELECT @InsertedStatusHistoryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();   -- grab newly inserted ID 

       PRINT 'New StatusHistory entry inserted with ID = ' + CAST(@InsertedStatusHistoryID AS VARCHAR(10))

       UPDATE @OrdersToUpdate
       SET StatusHistoryID = @InsertedStatusHistoryID
       WHERE OrderID = @OrderIDToInsert

       -- safety - reset @OrderIDToInsert to NULL so that we'll know when we're done
       SET @OrderIDToInsert = NULL

       -- read next OrderID to be processed
       SELECT TOP 1 @OrderIDToInsert = OrderID
       FROM @OrdersToUpdate
       WHERE StatusHistoryID IS NULL
       ORDER BY OrderID
    END 

    -- insert into the StatusHistoryForOrder table
    INSERT INTO dbo.StatusHistoryForOrder(OrderID, OrderStatusHistoryID)
        SELECT OrderID, StatusHistoryID
        FROM @OrdersToUpdate

    -- update your Orders to status ID = 16
    UPDATE dbo.Orders
    SET OrderStatusID = 16 
    FROM @OrdersToUpdate upd
    WHERE dbo.Orders.OrderID = upd.OrderID

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT 
       ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
       ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
       ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
       ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
       ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
       ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

This CTE basically joins your `Orders` table to the `StatusHistory` table (via the intermediate link table) and selects the values you're interested in (hopefully!).

Comment: @marc_s Your query didnt work,, don't know why. But I have may something similair a while ago:

Comment: @marc_s No rows again. I have no clue why. Even if I delete the entire where clause of your query still no rows. ?!?!?

Comment: @marc_s sorry sorry sorry. Like I said I am new to this. I traced the error back to databaseName.dbo.table instead of just dbo.table. Now your query works and returns 656 rows.

Comment: @marc_s I do not only want to update those rows,, I want the rows in [StatusHistoryForOrder] and [StatusHistory] to have a new row inserted in it. So I can remember the statushistory.

Comment: @synercoder: sure - at least now we're getting some data! :-)  So if I understand correctly, with those orders, you now want to 1) update their status to 16, and 2) insert a new row into the `StatusHistory` (and `StatusHistoryForOrder`) table, right? That's it, right??

Comment: @synercoder: OK, posted a first solution - can you give it a whirl?? (if possible on a test data set first!)

Comment: did not help. it printed: (0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

Comment: Just saw the error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_StatusHistory_Statuses". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.Statuses", column 'StatusId'.

Comment: @synercoder: ok, so you probably have to insert some other values for "StatusID" into the StatusHistory table - I don't know what those values might be..... also: is your table `Statuses` really in the **master** database??? You probably need a `USE (my database name here)` before executing my code, to be in the **right** database (where you have your tables!)

Comment: @marc_s did the use thing: error now is: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_StatusHistoryForOrder'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.StatusHistoryForOrder'. Line 58

Comment: @synercoder: racking my brain right now - those values should all be unique and new and thus I'm a bit puzzled about that message....

Comment: @synercoder: I have a hunch - could you use my code up to after the CTE inserts the data into the table variable? Can you do a `SELECT * FROM @OrdersToUpdate` right after that?? Do you see duplicate OrderID's in there??

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem seems solvable with set operations only.

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE (ID int, rownum int IDENTITY);
DECLARE @StatusHistory TABLE (ID int, rownum int IDENTITY);

/* get the list of orders with expired statuses */
INSERT INTO @Orders (ID)
SELECT o.OrderID
FROM Orders o
  INNER JOIN StatusHistoryForOrder shfo ON o.OrderID = shfo.OrderId
  INNER JOIN StatusHistory sh ON shfo.OrderStatusHistoryid = sh.OrderStatusHistoryId
GROUP BY o.OrderID
HAVING DATEDIFF(DD, MAX(sh.Date), GETDATE()) > 60

/* add so many new rows to StatusHistory and remember the new IDs */
INSERT INTO StatusHistory (OrderStatusId, Date, Message)
OUTPUT inserted.OrderStatusHistoryId INTO @StatusHistory (ID)
SELECT
  16,
  GETDATE(),
  'Auto-inserted as the previous status has expired'
FROM @Orders

/* join the two temp lists together and add rows to StatusHistoryForOrder */
INSERT INTO StatusHistoryForOrder (OrderId, OrderStatusHistoryid)
SELECT o.ID, sh.ID
FROM @Orders o
  INNER JOIN @StatusHistory sh ON o.rownum = sh.rownum

/* finally update the statuses in Orders */
UPDATE Orders
SET OrderStatusID = 16
FROM @Orders o
WHERE Orders.OrderID = o.ID
```

This should be the body of a single transaction, of course.

Comment: Your solution gives back: (18679 row(s) affected) while only 234 rows should be affected.